# Unable to access ContentVersion.VersionDataURL field

Tags: apex, contentversion

In the documentation of ContentVersion object, **VersionDataURL** field is mentioned. But when I'm trying to query the same in an Apex class, it is throwing an error saying -

**Error : No such column 'VersionDataUrl' on entity 'ContentVersion'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.**

When I ran the same query through Salesforce Query Editor, it successfully returned the result.

**Query :
Select Id, VersionDataUrl from ContentVersion limit 1**

This is quite weird and I have not found anything related to it in the salesforce documentation.

Comment: As per [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm) , 'VersionDataURL' field is available in API versions 55.0 and later, pls check if your apex class API version is above 55.0?

Comment: Hi @Vinay, It worked. I added the version as 56. In the doc it was mentioned that version should be 55.0 or above, so I thought it should work with 55.0 as well.
Thank You, Vinay

Comment: Thanks for confirming, I will post same as an answer so that it can help others too.  Will check with documentation team on API version.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment, 'VersionDataURL' field is available in API version 56.0 and later.  Updating apex class to V56.0 fixed the query issue.